# How do I make a plot with unevenly spaced interval on the x-axis?

Tags: python, plotly, x-axis

Is there a Python function for making a plot with unevenly spaced intervals on the x-axis, or how could I make the x-axis look like the image above?
[image: Click here to see the plot that I expected]

I tried to add separate traces using plotly, but the interval between each tick on the x-axis is always the same.
[image: The plot that I got]

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: @ChenyueRen I think the best available option would be to put together multiple subplots. You'll find an example in the post [Plotly: How to change the time resolution along the x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880549/plotly-how-to-change-the-time-resolution-along-the-x-axis/63882322#63882322)

Answer (score 0):

To plot your go.Figure with custom xaxis ticks, you may use `tickvals` and `ticktext`:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2.3,2.75, 3.2], y=[0, 1.4, 3.2,1]))
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[1.25, 1.5, 2.35, 3],ticktext=[1.25, 1.86, 2.35, 3])
```